# An astronomical saw

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, language

> In very similar manner,
>
> only one is successful,
>
> spending his wealth,
>
> a fruit for his health.
>
> What misery causes.

**Who am I?**

Hint:

> The title might be a bit old and out of fashion, but it tells you what is first

Hint 2:

> To get the first part you may consider the lines independent from each other

Hint 3:

> For the solution the right formulation of the first part matters

Comment: This is my first try at creating a puzzle and I think it has medium to hard difficulty. I might give a hint if there is no answer within 24 hours

Comment: The first letter of each line is IOSAW which might have something to do with the title (astronomical saw) and Io (one of Jupiter's moons) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)

Comment: @osdavison Not bad but you are looking in wrong place

Answer (score 3):

I haven't got much for this, but in case anyone else can see a link or perhaps suggest similar words:

In very similar manner,

> Like

only one is successful,

> Winner

spending his wealth,

> Squander?

a fruit for his health.

> Apple

What misery causes

> Tears?

Comment: The fourth line is good, for the rest not yet. Its always multiple words. Mind the first hint. :)

Answer (score 3):

(partial answer)

Are you a

> son?

---

"The title might be a bit old and out of fashion, but it tells you what is first"

> *Saw* is an old word for *saying* (i.e. a proverb). The lines in the riddle seem to be related to proverbs and idioms.

"An astronomical saw"

> "Astronomical" could refer to the Sun, which is a homophone of *son*.

"In very similar manner"

> "Like father, like son"

"only one is successful"

> ?

"spending his wealth"

> The Prodigal Son

"a fruit for his health"

> The fruit is an apple, as OP has already admitted. I believe this is related to the proverb "the apple never falls far from the tree", in which the apple is a metaphor for a son or daughter.

"What misery causes."

> ?

Comment: You are correct about the title, but the way the lines are connected is different than in most “Who am I?“-riddles, one reason for the enigmatic tag